# Is this systemd configuration will throw an error if the two programs run at the same time?

Tags: systemd

I created this laravel configuration using systemd.
And I have a little trouble understanding everything and testing everything.

Theoretically, if the "queue" and "schedule" processes are running at the same time, an error will occur because both are using the "artisan" program at the same time?

or the nohup program will run both processes at the same time and not cancel any process?

This configuration doesn't seems to conflict form now.

file `.ebextensions/01_files.config`

```yaml
files:
  "/etc/systemd/system/laravel_worker@.service":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [Unit]
      Description=Laravel %i worker
      After=network.target

      [Service]
      User=webapp
      Group=webapp
      EnvironmentFile=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env
      WorkingDirectory=/var/app/current/
      ExecStart=/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/php artisan %i:work
      Restart=on-failure
```

file `.ebextensions/02_commands.config`

```yaml
commands:
  01_setvars:
    command: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "export \(.key)=\"\(.value)\""' > /etc/profile.d/sh.local
  02_reload_daemon:
    command: systemctl daemon-reload
    ignoreErrors: true
packages:
  yum:
    jq: []

container_commands:
  01_laravel_worker_queue:
    command: systemctl enable laravel_worker@queue.service && systemctl restart laravel_worker@queue
    leader_only: true
  02_laravel_worker_schedule:
    command: systemctl enable laravel_worker@schedule.service && systemctl restart laravel_worker@schedule
    leader_only: true
```

Comment: If you want to prevent two systemd services from running at the same time, configure an explicit [`Conflicts=` dependency](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=) in the `[Unit]` section.

Answer (score 0):

As far as both `systemd` and `nohup` are concerned, `artisan` is not a program, but a parameter for program `/usr/bin/php`.

`nohup` does not care about any other programs or processes. **There's no reason you would not be able to start multiple instances of the same program if you want to.**

And running multiple instances of the same program (optionally with different parameters) is exactly what systemd service templates like your `laravel_worker@.service` are designed for.

---

However, I don't see the reason to use `nohup` when starting `/usr/bin/php artisan ...` as a systemd service.

Since it's configured as a system service (as opposed to a user service), systemd will take care of starting it fully separate from your session, so there will be no danger of it receiving a SIGHUP when you log out.

Since you don't have specified any `StandardOutput=` or `StandardError=` options in the service template, the standard output & standard error output from both instances will go to the default output location configured in `systemd-system.conf`, or if it does not exist, to the factory default destinations `StandardOutput=journal` and `StandardError=journal`. As a result, the standard output will not be a terminal, and so `nohup` might not redirect `php`'s output to `/var/app/current/nohup.out` as you might have expected.

And so, with or without `nohup`, the outputs and any errors should go to journal, viewable with `journalctl -u laravel_worker@queue.service` or `journalctl -u laravel_worker@schedule.service` respectively.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. I used nohup to not stop the other process in case the "queue" process was running at the same time as the "schedule" process.
And the journalctl -u looks very well. I will try to test more deeply during the day

Comment: The two processes run as separate instances. It's like opening two SSH connections in separate terminal windows to a remote server: if you forcibly close one terminal window, it should not cause any harm or any signals to be sent to processes started in the other terminal window. If the Laravel worker actively attempts to send a HUP to all Laravel processes running as the same user in some situation, then your worry might be real - but that would be Laravel's own doing, not `systemd`'s.